# Can someone explain this code in JavaScript with ++ and brackets?

Tags: javascript

```
var m=10;
n=(m++)+(++m)+(m++)+(++m);
```

Output is

```
n=48 m=14
```

How does this answer occur?

Answer (score 6):

Initially `m=10`. Now when `++` is executed, it will add 1 to the variable. In your code, there are 4 occurences of either `++m` or `m++`, so it will be 14 at the end.

When `++` appears before the variable like `++m`, it will add 1 first and use the variable in code. But when it appears after the variable like `m++`, the variable will be used first and then add 1.

So in `n=(m++)+(++m)+(m++)+(++m);`, 
`m++` - m will be used in code as 10 and becomes 11.
`++m` - `m` will be incremented by 1 first, so 11+1 =12 and will be used in code.
`m++` - m will be used in code as 12 and becomes 13.
`++m` - `m` will be incremented by 1 first, so 13+1 =14 and will be used in code.

So, final result will look like this:
`n=10+12+12+14`

```js
var m = 10;
var m1 = m++;
var m2 = ++m;
var m3 = m++;
var m4 = ++m;
var n = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4;
console.log('n: ' + n);
console.log('m: ' + m);
console.log('(m++): ' + m1 + ', (++m): ' + m2 + ', (m++): ' + m3 + ', (++m): ' + m4);

console.log('---');
var x = 10;
var y = (x++) + (++x) + (x++) + (++x);
console.log('y: ' + y);
console.log('x: ' + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

`m++` this will use previous value of m then increment.
`++m` this will first increment and then use the incremented value of m.

now,
`n=(m++)+(++m)+(m++)+(++m)`;

-> `m++` here the value of `m` will be first used then increased by 1. so expression will be `10 + (++m) + (m++) + (++m)`. and for further value of m will be 11.

-> for next it is `++m` so it will first increment then use in expression. so previously the value of m was 11, now 11+1 is 12. so expression will look like `10+12 + (m++) + (++m)`.

-> similarly to first point here also it will first used then increment. so expression will be `n=10+12+12+(++m)`. but after this the value of m is now 13.

-> so here `(++m)` it will first increment and then add. so previously the value was 13 so 13+1=14. so m is 14 and expression will be `n=10+12+12+14`.

so the value of `n=48` and `m=14`